# How to make text disappear once the app recognizes an image target on Vuforia/Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

How to make text disappear once the app recognizes an image target (via Vuforia)?

I'm trying to create an AR app which tells users instructions before they place their phone camera on a greeting card. How can I make this text disappear once the user projects their camera on the greeting card and recognizes one of the image targets associated with the card?

- Using Unity/ Vuforia for the AR App

Comment: Your exact difficulty is not very clear - you are not asking how to hide text, right? Do you mean you are looking for the place in the code where you know what target Vuforia recognizes?

Comment: https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/How-To-Use-the-Vuforia-Object-Recognition-Sample.html -> . Extend this script to implement custom event handling for your app.

Comment: @yakobom There is a text that tells users: "Point your phone camera to the card". I want this text to go away once the user points their phone camera to the card and the augmented reality functions start working (image target recognized via AR camera)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you are asking is very basic, you should start with a Vuforia sample and override the code that handles the detection of a target. It should be something like this:

```
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
       // hide your text here
    }
    else
    {
        // show your text here (or do anything else you wish to do)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage UIText object visibility in OnTrackableStateChanged of DefaultTrackableEventHandler script provided by Vuforia in sdk.

public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
        {
            if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
            {
                OnTrackingFound();
            }
            else
            {
                OnTrackingLost();
            }
        }

In OnTrackingFound() function you can do it. 
Create a public UItext object and in unity side drag your UItext to that public variable.

Answer (score 0):

Drop in this script any add anything you want to Start and Stop in the Event List in the Editor. For example to set a GameObject to active or not.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Vuforia;

public class ImageTargetBehaviour : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    public UnityEvent myStartEvent;
    public UnityEvent myStopEvent;

    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            // When target is found
            myStartEvent.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            // When target is lost
            myStopEvent.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The code where you written to spawn/visible the object after image detection, same place just hide the text like SetActive false.

Comment: hmm not exactly sure what you mean here. Can you expand on this?